# How do I properly individualize a Linux distro clone

Tags: linux, ssh, clone

I'd like to rsync my laptop's (=workstation's) root partition (assume Ubuntu for the sake of this question) to a couple of places. Assuming that the clones will meet in the same LAN and that the root partition covers everything but `/home`, what post-cloning modifications do I need to perform on each clone to individualize them reasonably well.

I suppose at the very least each clone should have its how `/etc/hostname` and that I should [regenerate](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-regenerate-openssh-host-keys/) each clone's ssh keys. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The only aspects that need to be individualized are things pertaining to networking and communications, as everything else is kept locally on each computer. You've already covered hostname. Seeing as you don't even mentioned the obvious case of IP conflict, I assume that you're using DHCP or that you otherwise have that covered.

I've successfully used the same flash card image by only accounting for the above two when copying between systems.

Other than that, there are only things relating to individual services that don't rely on the above to identify itself.

PS: For most cases it would work even without changing the hostname, but it is not recommended.